# how to understand the precision metric of sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hello I am working with sklearn and in order to understand better the metrics, I followed the following example of precision_score:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
print(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
```

the result that i got was the following:

0.222222222222

but I cant understand how sklearn computes this result since in the oficial page says that is computing the next formula: tp / (tp + fp) where tp is the number of the true positives and fp the number of false positives, but also is using the parameter called 'macro' which calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean and  this does not take label imbalance into account.
I would appreciated any explanation of this example thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to calculate precision for every label that you have:

- for label 0 precision is `tp / (tp + fp) = 2 / (2 + 1) = 0.66`
- for label 1 precision is `0 / (0 + 2) = 0`
- for label 2 precision is `0 / (0 + 1) = 0`

Final step is to calculate mean precision by all three labels: `precision = (0.66 + 0 + 0) / 3 = 0.22`

Comment: Thanks for the support, it's very clear your explanation Alexei.